# Why can I not put an edge loop around this model?

Tags: edges

I am unable to add an edge loop around the outer edge of [this model](http://toohey.co.uk/stackexchange/Stackexchange_EdgleLoopsProblem.blend) (around the rim), and it is driving me crazy trying to work out why.

- All faces in the model are quads (verified with `Select Faces By Sides`);
- I have removed all doubles;
- The relevant faces seem to be connected (verified by dragging them about).

Despite the above, you can see that any edge loop will only go through 6 faces and stop.

I made the object using mirror and array modifiers. I expect this is reason, but I cannot explain the persistent effect now that the modifiers have been applied.

I'm sure this is embarrassingly obvious, but I am clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform edge loops because your model has non manifold entities (vertexes and edges). You can select non manifold edges, delect them, then fill the faces correctly. T[image: non-manifold]o select non-manifold edges proceed as following image, then delete them, then fill with faces. (redo this step until you got no non-manifold edges).

Comment: Bingo. I had internal faces that I had managed to miss. Stupid error. Thank you very much.

Comment: no problem. Be aware of those "artifacts", specially if you go for 3D printing or work with CNC. External software doesn't handle with this, and will produce everything but expected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it happens but I know how to resolve:
Every part of the mesh where there are 2 faces loops between two spokes, delete the 4 vertices inbetween (they also are not selectable as edge loop), then recreate them, extruding or bridging edge loops and then loop cutting and grabbing in the right position.

Edit: deleting and recreating just one vertex is enough.

[image]